# Lost Contacts icon

Tags: contacts, icon

My wife has lost the Contacts icon on her iPhone 6. Contacts are still listed uner the telephone icon, but there is no Contacts icon. We have looked in the Extras folder and it is not there. We have done a sesrch for Contacts as suggested and there is no indication of what folder it might be in. We also re-set her home screen to factory settings and still nothing. Are there any other ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It may have been removed. You can add it again using the App Store:

> #### Restore a built-in app that you removed
>
> 1. Go to the App Store.
> 2. Search for the app. Make sure that you use the exact name of the app. [Find the correct name of built-in apps.](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204221#names)
> 3. Tap <sub>[image]</sub> to restore the app.
> 4. Wait for the app to restore, then open it from your Home screen.

<sup>[Remove built-in Apple apps from the Home screen on your iOS device with iOS 10](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204221)</sup>